# Variables not generated in script task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, script-task, ssis-2017

For some reason my variables which I have added to the readonlyvariables(also tried readwritevariables)are not generated in code when I want to use them in code. What am I missing? I've added this script task in the Control Flow. When adding it in a data flow, it works fine. Is this the problem?

Regards!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a Script Task you have to use the following syntax:

```
Dts.Variables["varInputFile"].Value
```

**Reference**

- [Using Variables in the Script Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/task/using-variables-in-the-script-task?view=sql-server-2017#variables-example)

Comment: Thnx, it did work. Do you know why they made this difference? One time you can use Variables. the other time you need to use your answer...

Comment: @Miscode check the following article, you will find the difference in the comparison table: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/comparing-the-script-task-and-the-script-component?view=sql-server-2017